# Lanczos algorithm

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, algorithm

How can I implement this method ,,Lanczos algorithm " through Mathematica?
This method solves eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2274004).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that this Q is "easily found in the documentation," but the following was easily found in [`Eigenvalues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html) by searching the docs for "lanczos eigenvalues":

> The "Arnoldi" method is also known as a Lanczos method when applied to symmetric or Hermitian matrices.

The Arnoldi method has suboptions that are explained in the documentation of [`Eigenvalues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html).

Comment: Thank you for replay. I have to program this method